# How to change the age rating on iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store

I finished my first mobile app, available in the Google Play Store. But when I tried to publish it on the App Store (iOS only), I got this message:

> You must select the frequency level for each Apple content description
> in the Age Rating section

In age rating section it says « None age rating » but I didn’t see any place to add one?

Where can I add it? In publish page or directly in parameter information inside the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it on App Store Connect. First, select your current build (if your app is already on the app store, you will need to create a new version).

<kbd>[image: "1.0.5 Prepare for Submission" selected]</kbd>

Them, scroll down to **General App Information**. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button to edit the age rating.

<kbd>[image: Edit button to the right of "Age Rating"]</kbd>

This popup will appear. Fill in the questionnaire, and once you're done, your age rating will be shown at the bottom.

<kbd>[image: Multiple choice questions all answered, resulting age rating shown at bottom]</kbd>